# building gradle project info stuck with no status

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, import

[image: stuck for ever]

my android studio 1.5.1 cant open any project that i downloaded and just stuck in this loading for ever, no status like downloading gradle or somrthing! but can open my own projects! 
Im runnig windows 10 build 10586 and JDK 8 update 66.

I tried:

- 1.restarting laptop
- 2.reinstalling studio or installing previous version (1.4.1)
- 3.using offline work or not.
- 4.deleting .gradle folder from C:/User/name/.gradle
- 5.using gradle wrapper or local gradle with downloading Gradle 2.10-all.zip or even gradle 2.4-all.zip from http://gradle.org/gradle-download/

even if i click on cancel button, nothings happen and studio just keep the loading and I just can kill android studio process from task manager!

Comment: same here.What you have done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cant open any project that i downloaded

That could be due to your country or your location which is downloaded with ip changer or something like that.

Try to use another ip changer and make sure that project is working or try with another project.

Perhaps, something is not downloaded completly and you should try that with an another project.

hope that helps.