# Cannot import downloaded projects in Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, webrtc, android-studio-2.1

I have setup the latest version of Android Studio (2.1) and I am trying to import some downloaded project from github to build from the studio.

Every time I try importing the projects it keeps loading at the **Building 'xxxxxx' Gradle project info** The cancel button also have no effect.

I am trying to build the following projects :

- https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo
- https://github.com/pristineio/apprtc-android

Here is another similar issue ([building gradle project info stuck with no status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813094/building-gradle-project-info-stuck-with-no-status)) but I tried using psiphon 3 but no help.

I am not sure how an ip changer can affect an android studio project build. I am not sure about the other options provided there (3, 4, 5).

I am using windows 7, java 1.8 and android studio 2.1.3

Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: The first one Is not working anyway -- see here -- https://github.com/pristineio/apprtc-android/issues/1

Comment: Ok.. but why am I not able to import the project ?? Is there anyway I can get more details about what is actually happening behind the loading bar and get some logs may be ?

Comment: How long did you wait? The first build can take some time as all the dependencies need to be downloaded.

Comment: I waited for 5-8 minutes. Is there some way I can track the download progress or may be download the dependencies beforehand ?? I am new to gradle and android studio so I am not sure how this is handled !!

Comment: You can start the build from the command line. For example on Windows go to the project's home directory and type `gradlew build`.